# Checking if a Relation is Transitive

Tags: relations

I have

$$R = \{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1),(3,1),(2,1),(4,4),(4,2),(3,2),(4,3)\}$$

Is this relation transitive? I think since $(2,1), (1,4) \in R$ to be transitive $(2,4) \in R$ since $(2,4) \notin R$, $R$ is not transitive.

Comment: It looks like you meant transitive rather than reflexive.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig lol .. yeah.Noticed that just now before reading your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. $(2,1)\in R$ and $(1,4)\in R$, but $(2,4)\not\in R$. Therefore, $R$ is not [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation).